# NCD -nodejs certified developer

Tags: node.js

Can someone guide me how do I register for NDC exam, I have gone through https://foundation.nodejs.org/resources/certification webpage and it always points to a googlegoogle form Register forEarly Access!

I am a bit confused from where shall I register to appear for the certification ?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the certification program will be available from mid of 2019.

"We anticipate the program being available mid-2019."

Comment: Post this in comments section